# Android ABI linked to wrong target

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, docker, android-sdk-tools

I am installing Android SDK on Linux, via terminal, like that:

```
ENV ANDROID_SDK_FILENAME android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz
ENV ANDROID_SDK_URL http://dl.google.com/android/${ANDROID_SDK_FILENAME}
ENV ANDROID_API_LEVELS android-23

ENV ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION 24.0.1

ENV ANDROID_HOME /opt/android-sdk-linux
ENV PATH ${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools

RUN cd /opt && \
    wget -q ${ANDROID_SDK_URL} && \
    tar -xzf ${ANDROID_SDK_FILENAME} && \
    rm ${ANDROID_SDK_FILENAME}

RUN echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter tools --force
RUN echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter platform-tools --force
RUN echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter ${ANDROID_API_LEVELS} --force
RUN echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter addon-google_apis-google-23 --force
RUN echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter build-tools-${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION} --force
RUN echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-android-support --force
RUN echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter sys-img-x86_64-google_apis-23 --force
RUN echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter sys-img-armeabi-v7a-google_apis-23 --force
```

After installation I list android targets and I have:

```
Available Android targets:
---------- id: 1 or "android-23"
     Name: Android 6.0
     Type: Platform
     API level: 23
     Revision: 3
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in  
     Tag/ABIs : google_apis/armeabi-v7a, google_apis/x86_64
---------- id: 2 or "Google Inc.:Google APIs:23"
     Name: Google APIs
     Type: Add-On
     Vendor: Google Inc.
     Revision: 1
     Description: Android + Google APIs
     Based on Android 6.0 (API level 23)
     Libraries:
      * com.android.future.usb.accessory (usb.jar)
          API for USB Accessories
      * com.google.android.media.effects (effects.jar)
          Collection of video effects
      * com.google.android.maps (maps.jar)
          API for Google Maps
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in 
     Tag/ABIs : no ABIs.
```

I need google_apis/armeabi-v7a, google_apis/x86_64 to be linked with Google Inc.:Google APIs:23. How to achieve that? Surprisingly, when device image is created from Android Studio, they match correctly.